# CoreData: Large quantity of entities or store an array as Transformable?

Tags: ios, core-data, nscoding

I am making a game where every creature can have 3 attacks and every attack can have many effects at the same time. I'm using CoreData to hold all of the data.

A basic example of what my problem is can be seen with three entities:

1. `Creature`: contains a to-many relationship to `Attack` entity
2. `Attack`: contains a to-many relationship to `Effect` entity
3. `Effect`: contains the details of the effect (damage, confuse, poison, etc)

So to begin I need to have three unique `Attack` entities for each unique `Creature` entity. Then I would need to add the `Effect` entities to each attack. My problem is that each effect can have a different value but it is basically the same effect as all the other creatures: It is still "Damage" but the value of the damage is different from each creature.

There are only two ways i've thought of doing this:

1. Create a unique `Effect` for each `Attack` for each `Creature`, this way I could store the effect value inside the entity. The disadvantage of this would be that the data could grow big: 3x3x400 = 3,600 `Effect` entities that only exist to have a single relationship each.
2. Create one `Effect` for each type (damage, confuse, etc) and use a Transformable data type in the `Attack` entity where I store an array of dictionaries containing each `Effect` entity identifier (so that they can be found when needed) and the value for that effect. This can be easily handled by `NSCoding` automatically and would reduce the amount of `Entity` object from 3,600 to probably 20.

The `Effect` & `Attack` entities are rarely accessed (only when the creature is in a battle) and I do not need to search inside them, therefore I think that would not be a noticeable performance impact. I have also read in many websites that they suggest not to store arrays and dictionaries in CoreData. Is there any other way of doing this? and if not, what option would be better?

PS: Sorry for the non descriptive title, I could not figure out what to put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan to change the kinds of your effects you could have an entity that you could call `CreatureAttack` where each row completely specifies the effects of a creature's attack. The columns might be: foreign key to a `Creature`, foreign key to an `Attack`, `Damage`, `Confuse`, `Poison`, etc. For each effect column a row would have a value of the effect for this attack and creature.

This entity will only have at most #`Creature` x #`Attack` rows and you can find out everything about a creature's attack by pulling just one row.

Otherwise I think solution 1 is cleaner and the performance hit of having a few thousand rows should be negligible especially if you put an index on the `Creature` foreign key and/or a compound index on both `Creature` and `Attack` foreign keys (supported in iOS5).

Comment: I had not thought about this approach. The problem here is that if I wanted to add a new type of effect I would have to update the Core Data Model. However the effects will probably not change too much throughout the lifetime of the game, so this option might be feasible. Thank you!